# Difference between "def setup" and "setup do" in Minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

Are there any differences at all between calling `def setup` and `setup do` in Rails Minitests? I had been using `def setup` this whole time, but I suddenly found that my `setup` for a particular test file was not being called. When I changed it to `setup do`, it suddenly worked again (without changing anything else). But I find this very peculiar, and I'd rather stick to `def setup` for everything if possible, for consistency. Any advice is appreciated.

```rb
require 'test_helper'
require_relative '../../helpers/user_helper'

class FooTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include UserHelper

  # This method doesn't get called as-is.
  # But it does get called if I change the below to `setup do`.
  def setup
    # create_three_users is a UserHelper method.
    create_three_users
    @test_user = User.first
  end


  test 'should abc' do
    # Trying to call @test_user here returned nil.
  end
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was another test file with the class defined as `class FooTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase`. I imagine someone created it by copying the original `FooTest` file, and forgot to change the name.

In short, the other `FooTest`'s setup method had been getting called instead of this one. Coincidentally, the other `FooTest` had also been calling the same `create_three_users` in the setup, which was why I didn't realise this till I tried and failed to assign an instance variable.

I couldn't find much info on the actual difference between `def setup` and `setup do`, but one [blog](http://docs.komagata.org/5203) (you'll have to take my word because it's written in Japanese) writes that `setup do` calls the setup process for not only that class but also the its parent class, which might explain why my tests worked using `setup do` (maybe it called the `setup` for both `FooTest`s).

Answer (score 3):

From the [Rails docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/SetupAndTeardown.html) for `ActiveSupport::Testing::SetupAndTeardown`:

> Adds support for `setup` and `teardown` callbacks. These callbacks
> serve as a replacement to overwriting the `#setup` and `#teardown`
> methods of your `TestCase`.
>
> ```rb
> class ExampleTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
>  setup do
>    # ...
>  end
>
>  teardown do
>    # ...
>  end
> end
> ```

Which is likely a reference to Minitest's `setup` and `teardown` [lifecycle hooks](https://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/Minitest/Test/LifecycleHooks.html#method-i-setup).